# How to make that the drag drop operation over a telerik RadScheduleView copy (not move) the appointment

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, telerik, radscheduleview

I have a control with a List Box containing some appointments that can be drag drop over a RadScheduleView. This is working fine but i want to copy (not move) the appointment. If it is possible I want to handle the creation of the new appointment because i'm inheriting from Appointment and added a new property to the class.

I know that drag copy can be done using Ctrl key while dragging but i want to make copy the default behavior.

Maybe forcing the Ctrl key to be pressed when the user clicks on the List Box Item could work. I don't know how to do the last but anyway doesn't seems to be the best approach.

this is a sketch of the control. drag drop from list box to schedule view should copy. drag drop between schedule view should move.
[image: control with list box and schedule view]

If someone needs more details, please comment and I'll edit. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research i found how to make copy by default. I'm answering my own question so people can use it.

The class in charge of the DragDrop source (the ListBox) is Telerik.Windows.DragDrop.Behaviors.ListBoxDragDropBehavior. We just need to implement our own class that inherits from Telerik.Windows.DragDrop.Behaviors.ListBoxDragDropBehavior and use it in the xaml when creating the ListBox like this:

```
<ListBox>
    <drag:ListBoxDragDrop.Behavior>
        <loc:ListBoxDragDropBehavior/>
    </drag:ListBoxDragDrop.Behavior>
</ListBox>
```

We only have to change IsMovingItems to get the copy behavior by default.

```
class ListBoxDragDropBehavior :    Telerik.Windows.DragDrop.Behaviors.ListBoxDragDropBehavior
{
    protected override bool IsMovingItems(DragDropState state)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

That's all. Hope it helps.